# exception handling of two different api calls in completablefuture

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, concurrency, completable-future

i have two methods each one call a rest api i need to call them in one thread and run asynchronously so i used completeblefuture and enclosed both of call in one method, my problem is i couldn't be able to know the exception raised from which one of them, is that possible ? or as long as they're run in one thread i can just use completeExceptionally method in completeblefuture and log the exception as there is error in calling first api or second api, does it that make sense or it will be not helpful for caller?

Here a simulation of that scenario

```
// first api
public Codes findCodes(String codeID) {
        Codes result = null;
        try {
            result = restTemplate.getForObject("localhost:8080/api/codes?id=" + codeID, Codes.class);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // log(e) there is an error in calling codes api
        }
        return result;
    }

//second api 
public Point findPoints(String userName) {
        Point result = null;
        try {

            result = restTemplate.getForObject("localhost:8080/api/points?userName=" + userName, Point.class);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // log(e) there is an error in calling points api
        }
        return result;
    }

//method calling both of them 

    @Async
public CompletableFuture<PointsWithCodesResponse> callTwoApis(String userName, String codeID) {
    PointsWithCodesResponse response = new PointsWithCodesResponse();
    response.setCodes(findCodes(codeID));
    response.setPoints(findPoints(userName));
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(response).exceptionally(t -> {
        //log and handle ex, how to know if it's from first api or second
        return null;
    });
}
```

both of api is used in other parts in application and each one of them has it's own handling for exception and logging

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you currently have, preferably in the form of a [mcve]. Code often describes the situation much clearer than words (though words are also helpful). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: i edited it and set a snippet of code which describe the situation

Comment: This doesn't work, a future created with `completedFuture` will never throw an exception, so the `exceptionally` part will never get triggered.  Furthermore, your `@Async` method should return a `CompletableFuture` that isn't completed yet, so the work can be done in the background.  Instead, you do all the work in the method already and just wrap the result in a future.